# SVGPathSeg is deprecated and will be removed in Chrome 48. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5708851034718208

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, d3.js, svg

Getting SVGPathSeg is deprecated and will be removed in Chrome 48. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5708851034718208 error in my angular application because i am using 'pathSegList' in my code with D3 like this d3.select('.data1').node().pathSegList

How to fix this? If it is not supported in  Chrome 48 what will be the alternative for this? Any one can help me

Comment: Thanks Longson. I will check

Comment: This is the answer gave by Robert. Thanks Robert.   There will be a new API
https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData
and a polyfill for that
https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js
as well as a polyfill for the old API
https://github.com/progers/pathseg
Also see the official chromium bug
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539385